# I keep getting "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully" when trying to install tensorflow-gpu on ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, setup.py, python-packaging

I tried updating setuptools but still unsuccessful.

```
    .....
    Collecting tensorflow-gpu

    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [39 lines of output]
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: You need to include the complete error message and/or output of pip, else we cannot guess what the problem is.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know more about the environment: OS, Python version, pip version, which command was run, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

after more digging I found out that tensorflow-gpu is no longer supported, according to https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/ it has been replaced with an empty package that will generate an error upon installation.

```
    =========================================================
    The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!
 
    Please install "tensorflow" instead.
 
    Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
    since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
    information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
    =========================================================
```